# Angular2- delay in ngModelChange

Tags: javascript, angular

What is the best way to add an delay for a `ngModelChange`property binding?

**Example:** I want to call a function in an input field:

```
<input [ngModel]="model" (ngModelChange)="func()">
```

The model update on every input change.

Was `func()` just called, it should, although the model was changed, be possible to call `func()` again only after for example 3 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would leverage a control to do that:

```
<input [ngModel]="model" [ngFormControl]="ctrl">
```

and leverage the `valueChanges` property this way:

```
constructor() {
  this.ctrl = new Control();
  this.ctrl.valueChanges.delay(3000).subscribe((value) => {
    this.func();
  });
```

This issue in Github could also interest you:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6895